# Web app that will parse a Russian sentence

Tags: web-apps, hosted, language

I am primarily looking for a free site that will parse a Russian sentence.

Before posting this, my searches led me to [**Link Grammar Parser**](https://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/), but it looks as if the only way to use it is to download it and I'd prefer not to do that for all the usual reasons.

Answer (score 3):

There is exactly what you want: http://sz.ru/parser/

Comment: Perhaps this is the best there is, but I didn't find it very helpful in terms of trying to parse this sentence: Моё место домой.  I suppose a big part of the problem is that I don't understand all the letters that make up the diagram and what they represent.  Nor did I find any page that described them.  Is there one?

Comment: @LisaBeck "Моё место домой" is not a valid sentence.